# How do I know which tags I have created?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Whenever I do not find the best matching tag for my question, I create a new tag. By this time, I have created around 5-6 tags. But don't remember them.

Is there any way to know which tags I have created?

Comment: I *think* the only record that is kept is when a description was added to a tag, not really when the tag itself was suggested. Each tag [has a history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3620111/revisions) showing who first added info about it.